# Incrontab doesn't detect modifications on a s3fs mount

Tags: linux, inotify, s3fs

This is my `incrontab` line:

```
/srv/www IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_MOVE rsync --quiet 
--recursive --links --hard-links --perms --acls --xattrs --owner --group --delete --force /var/www_s3/ /var/www
```

`/var/www_s3/` is an s3fs mount. However, it only gets kicked off when a file is modified manually; nothing happens when a file is changed/added on S3.

Is there a way to get incrontab to detect these changes?

Comment: can you please follow-up with the developers of sf3fs? They replied to the issue I started there for this:  http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=385? They need additional information to work your specific issue further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often the case that FUSE based filesystems only support a subset of the features that the underlying filesystems support. It's generally some aspect of one or more of these features which is limiting the incrontab entry from detecting the change on the remote side.

At any rate I thought it best to inquire about this on the s3fs project, and so posted this question there asking the developers for guidance on any potential limitations.

You can track this issue/question here: [Issue 385: incrontab & s3fs support?](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=385)

#### References

- [incrontab man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)
- [FUSE-based file system backed by Amazon S3](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/)